# Collecting files from two locations into one recursive list

Tags: python, recursion

I have two locations in which I need to recursively loop through and collect all files that are .jpg. That part I can easily do. My question is, how can I easily combine or collect the files from the network location and the local location, into a single multi-dimensional list so i can then recursively loop through them as if they were one location virtually.

The last part is the most important, because I need to loop through them in order of heirarchy in order to properly create an interface menu for the application I'm working in. Hopefully the image helps explain what I'm trying to do.

So at the end when i loop through the list of collected files it's mimicking as if they were in a single location. I'm not sure how the best way to approach this would be. I wouldn't actually be moving files, just storing them into a list representing it.

[image]

```
import os

directory = "C:\\Users\\ToolSets"

files = []  
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):

    files.sort()
    for f in files:
        if not f.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
            continue

        # get category name from folders
        cat = (root[len(directory)+1:]).replace('\\','/') 
        cat += ('/{}').format(os.path.splitext(f)[0])
        print cat, f
```

The final output printed should look like this:

```
Family img.jpg
Family img-01.jpg
Family ncle01.jpg
Family zebra.jpg
Family/Home family.jpg
Family/Home kid.jpg
Family/Vacation leslie.jpg
Family/Vacation john.jpg
Misc candy.jpg
Misc sucker.jpg
```

Comment: Do you want to move the files from one location to other?

Comment: You say you don't actually want to move the files but then your example uses `os.walk()`, which is going to traverse the *actual* filesystem. Do you want to use the actual system or a facade?

Comment: @RajanChauhan no I do not want to actually move the files

Comment: I use os.walk to collect the initial files from the two locations

Comment: A solution to this could be making a webpage to storing all the full path of images listing or showing them. So you can see all your images at same page without actually moving them in the filesystem.

Comment: a list does not seem like the appropriate structure for this.Why don't you use a tree instead

Comment: neither of these solutions would work. they are over complicating it.